# Need help on understanding Google Maps API quota

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api, quota

I'm currently using some Google Maps API (Geocoding, Maps Javascript, Places) in my ASP.NET solution and found out there is quota for number of requests called per day (as you can see in the following picture)
[image: -]

It seems that after my ASP.NET is once loaded, the quota has reached its limit and would make me to register for the billing account. I just want to ask what do each quota name in the picture mean? (Or how different is one from each other. Since this is just for testing/development purpose and not for commercial, is there a way to adjust the quota limit without registering the billing account? (I'm just an intern worker so I am not provided funds to register for one yet)

Any response would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

seems you reached the limit per day in trial mode. only one request per day remains available.

the other quotas are api calls per second, to control flooding. but the limits in your screenshot for these 2 quotas don't make sense if you have a single call per day.

you have no choice but to create a bill account or use another service account to execute the api.